# Angular Bootstrap: Tooltip placement based on function

Tags: angularjs, angular-bootstrap, angularjs-bootstrap

I'm using the [Angular Bootstrap Popover](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/popover):

```
<button popover-placement="top" popover="On the Top!" class="btn btn-default">Top</button>
```

If using default [Bootstrap JavaScript](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips), it's possible to define the `placement` using a function.

How can this be done using Angular Bootstrap? I would like to switch from `right` to `left` on a mobile device. (width < 768 px).

Comment: have you tried this solution: https://github.com/AnalogJ/matchmedia-ng

Answer (score 2, accepted):

define one variable 'placement' in controller for placement. and change html code to

```
<button popover-placement="{{placement}}" popover="On the Top!" class="btn btn-default">Top</button>
```

now you can change placement of tooltip in controller on condition